# Divide a task in to OperationQueue is slower than run all it one time

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

Version 1:

```
 func longTask(for myData:Data){

     let tick = Date() // startTime

     let fileDataLength = myData.count
     let count = 0

     while count < fileDataLength{

        //task 1
        task1Result = task1()

        //task 2
        task2Result = task2(task1Result)

        //task 3
        task3 result = task3(task1Result)

        count = count + incrementCount

     }
    NSLog("%f",tick.timeInterverSinceNow) // print out -0.06
  }
```

Version 2:

```
func longTask(for myData: Data ){

     let fileDataLength = myData.count

     let count = 0

     let testQueue = OperationQueue()

     while count < fileDataLength{

        //task 1
        task1Result = task1()
        {
           // store all needed value
           let name:String = task1Result.mane
           ...
           testQueue.addOperation{ // do in other thread

              //task 2
              task2Result = task2(name:name , ...)

             //task 3
             task3 result = task3(....)
           }
        }()
        count = count + incrementCount

     }
    testQueue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()        
    NSLog("%f",tick.timeInterverSinceNow) // print out -0.5

}
```

in version 2, I imagined if *longTask* is run by thread A, by move task 2 and 3 to thread B  *while* loop will do next *task1()* in thread A while thread B running task2() and task3(). This will reduce the execute time but Version 2 is slower than Version 1 about 10 times. What was I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

your strategy seems to be OK, but we don't know nothing about your real code. try this in your playground

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

import Foundation

let q = OperationQueue()
let start = Date()
print("start at", start)

let n = 4
var gs = [Int]()

for j in 0..<n {
    gs.append(0)

    //q.addOperation {
        var s = 0
        for i in 0..<1000 {
            s += i
        }
        gs[j] = s
        let t = Date()
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            let pt = Date()
            print(s, j, "calculated:", t.timeIntervalSince(start), "printed:", pt.timeIntervalSince(start))
        }
    //}
}

q.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
print(gs, "GRANT TOTALL:", gs.reduce(0, +), "finished in", Date().timeIntervalSince(start), "seconds\n")
```

in my own environment

Processor Name: Intel Core i5
Processor Speed:    2,6 GHz
Number of Processors:   1
Total Number of Cores:  2
L2 Cache (per Core):    256 KB 
L3 Cache:   3 MB
Memory: 16 GB

it prints

```
start at 2017-04-24 11:47:03 +0000
[499500, 499500, 499500, 499500] GRANT TOTALL: 1998000 finished in 0.327317953109741 seconds

499500 0 calculated: 0.0641489624977112 printed: 0.419835984706879
499500 1 calculated: 0.130355000495911 printed: 0.420383989810944
499500 2 calculated: 0.230241000652313 printed: 0.420827984809875
499500 3 calculated: 0.326637983322144 printed: 0.421335995197296
```

but with help of OperationQueue

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

import Foundation

let q = OperationQueue()
let start = Date()
print("start at", start)

let n = 4
var gs = [Int]()

for j in 0..<n {
    gs.append(0)

    q.addOperation {
        var s = 0
        for i in 0..<1000 {
            s += i
        }
        gs[j] = s
        let t = Date()
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            let pt = Date()
            print(s, j, "calculated:", t.timeIntervalSince(start), "printed:", pt.timeIntervalSince(start))
        }
    }
}

q.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
print(gs, "GRANT TOTALL:", gs.reduce(0, +), "finished in", Date().timeIntervalSince(start), "seconds\n")
```

it prints

```
start at 2017-04-24 11:58:45 +0000
[499500, 499500, 499500, 499500] GRANT TOTALL: 1998000 finished in 0.186473965644836 seconds

499500 0 calculated: 0.0701659917831421 printed: 0.388468980789185
499500 1 calculated: 0.131179988384247 printed: 0.389105975627899
499500 2 calculated: 0.165158987045288 printed: 0.389568984508514
499500 3 calculated: 0.18574994802475 printed: 0.389993965625763
```

As expected, the code runs quicker

What about the gs array? Is it thread safe?? NO!! So finally we need to add some synchronisation, even though it seems as not required in our very simple example ...

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

import Foundation

let q = OperationQueue()
let start = Date()
print("start at", start)

let n = 4
var gs = [Int]()
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "MyArrayQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

for j in 0..<n {
    queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        gs.append(0)
    }

    q.addOperation {
        var s = 0
        for i in 0..<1000 {
            s += i
        }
        queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            gs[j] = s
        }

        let t = Date()
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            let pt = Date()
            print(s, j, "calculated:", t.timeIntervalSince(start), "printed:", pt.timeIntervalSince(start))
        }
    }
}

q.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
var mgs:[Int] = []
queue.sync {
    mgs = gs
}
print(mgs, "GRANT TOTALL:", mgs.reduce(0, +), "finished in", Date().timeIntervalSince(start), "seconds\n")
```

final result

```
start at 2017-04-24 14:38:12 +0000
[499500, 499500, 499500, 499500] GRANT TOTALL: 1998000 finished in 0.164229989051819 seconds

499500 0 calculated: 0.0660730004310608 printed: 0.324115991592407
499500 1 calculated: 0.0995810031890869 printed: 0.324918031692505
499500 2 calculated: 0.126493990421295 printed: 0.325313985347748
499500 3 calculated: 0.162481009960175 printed: 0.32580304145813
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think i knew the problem here. if call addOperation 1000 time without add a single code inside , it is still consume 0.3 seconds (i5,8gb). So that It plus 0.3 in total runing time